# Exraer objetos de un array con js

Tags: javascript, ajax

Quiero meter en HTML las rutas que trae mi array desde json mediante el append

```
$.ajax({
    url:"ajax/ventas.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(respuesta){


    //console.log("respuesta", respuesta);
    console.log("respuesta",respuesta[9]);

    $("#media").append(
                        

           }
      })
```

Esto es lo que trae mi array de respuesta:

```
vistas/img/tickets/10097/descarga (1).jpg,vistas/img/tickets/10097/descarga (2).jpg,vistas/img/tickets/10097/descarga.jpg,vistas/img/tickets/10097/descarga.png
vistas/img/tickets/10096/descarga1.jpg
```

Saludos cordiales

Comment: ¿Quieres meter las rutas como string en el html o como imágenes?

Comment: Quiero meter las rutas en el html como imagenes

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con un ciclo

```js
const respuesta = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg"];

for(const img of respuesta){
  jQuery("#media").append(`<img src="${img}" />`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="media"></div>
```